# How do I use Array Methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand that arrays contain data in an organizing fashion, and that you can append, remove etc to them.  However, I'm not sure how to structure my code or if I'm understanding this correctly.

The task:

```
describe "no_fruits?" do
  it "returns false for non-empty array" do
    ary = ["apple", "banna"]
    expect( no_fruits?(ary) ).to eq(false)
  end

  it "returns true for empty array" do
    ary = []
    expect( no_fruits?(ary) ).to eq(true)
  end
end

describe "number_of_fruits" do
  it "returns the number of fruits" do
    ary1 = ["apple", "banana"]
    ary2 = ["apple", "papaya", "kiwi"]
    expect( number_of_fruits(ary1, ary2) ).to eq(5)
  end
end

describe "number_of_unique_fruits" do
  it "returns the number of unique fruits in an array with duplicates" do
    expect( number_of_unique_fruits(["apple", "apple", "banana", "kiwi"]) ).to eq(3)
  end

  it "returns the number of unique fruits in an array without duplicates" do
    expect( number_of_unique_fruits(["apple", "banana", "papaya", "kiwi"]) ).to eq(4)
  end
end
```

My attempt so far:

```
def no_fruits?(a)
 if a 
   false
else (a.empty?)
  true
   end
end

def number_of_fruits(a1, a2)
  a1=["apple", "banana"]
  a2=5
end

def number_of_unique_fruits()
  number_of_unique_fruits.uniq
  number_of_unique_fruits.uniq!
end
```

Comment: There is no rush to select an answer. Quick selections can discourage other, possibly better answers, and are not appreciated by members who are still preparing their answers when the green checkmark flashes. Consider waiting at least a couple of hours in future.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I didn't completely understand your task but from your code I think it should be like this:

```
def no_fruits?(a)
  a.empty?
end

def number_of_fruits(a1, a2)
  a1.count + a2.count
end

def number_of_unique_fruits(a)
  a.uniq.count
end
```

The last method should also receive an array. Please try this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes!  Thank you, I was very unsure about how to structure this and your code instantly made sense to me just by reading it.

Comment: The first method could be change to `a.empty?`, there is not need for an `if` block.

Comment: For `number_of_fruits` why construct a new array before counting? Why not just `a1.count + a2.count`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't know the impact of both means constructing an array and then counting or doing the way you denoted, it seems similar to me. But will go with your way and edit the answer accordingly. Thanks for denoting a better way.

Answer (score 1):

```
def no_fruits?(*arrays)
  arrays.flatten.empty?
end

def number_of_fruits(*arrays)
  arrays.flatten.count
end

def number_of_unique_fruits(*arrays)
  arrays.flatten.uniq.count
end
```

The strange little character in front of the `*arrays` argument is called [the splat operator](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/). It gathers up any remaining arguments passed to the method in an array. By using it our method now can handle any possible number of fruity arrays.

So if we call:

```
number_of_fruits(['apple'], ['pear'],['orange', 'plum'])
```

The `arrays` argument would equal:

```
[['apple'], ['pear'],['orange', 'plum']]
```

We then use [`Array#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-flatten) which takes an array of arrays and recursivly flattens them:

```
irb(main):006:0> [['apple'], ['pear'],['orange', 'plum']].flatten
=> ["apple", "pear", "orange", "plum"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def no_fruits?(a)
  a.empty?
end

def number_of_fruits(a1, a2)
  number_of_unique_fruits(a1) + number_of_unique_fruits(a2) 
end

def number_of_unique_fruits(a)
  a.uniq.count
end
```

And as Deep said last method should receive an array.